# Java calculator that takes in expressions

Tags: java, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator that adds and subtracts numbers entered from the user that are in parenthesis.
Here is a sample run:

> Welcome to the Expression Program
> Enter a line of expressions:
> ( 2 + 3 + -4 + 5 ) (6+7+8+-9)( 3 + -2 +7+0)
> The value of “( 2 + 3 + -4 + 5 )” is 6
> The value of “(6+7+8+-9)” is 12
> The value of “( 3 + -2 +7+0)” is 8
> Goodbye!

> Welcome to the Expression Program
> Enter a line of expressions:
> (6) () (hello + friend ) ( 1 * 2 + 4 ) 7+8+9)
> The value of “(6)” is 6
> ERROR: “” is not an integer
> ERROR: “hello” is not an integer
> ERROR: “*” is not a valid operator
> ERROR: Illegal start character ‘7’Goodbye!

**This is what I have so far but it is not working:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExprParser 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    
    Scanner g=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Expression Program!");
    System.out.println("Enter a line of expressions(between parenthesis):");
    String exp=g.next();
    String[] arr=exp.split("\\)");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) 
    {   System.out.println(arr[i]+")");
        int result=calculate(arr[i]);
        System.out.println(calculate(Integer.toString(result)));
    }
}
    
public static int calculate(String a)
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<a.length();++i)
    {
        
        char sign='+';
        a.indexOf(sign);

             sum+=Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0,sign))+Integer.parseInt(a.substring(sign+1,sign));
        
    }
    return sum;
}   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" What is the output or errors?

Comment: There's no way the code that you pasted ouputs those error messages. Is this homework?

Comment: @DesertIvy It is saying there is an out of bounce error in my substring(0,sign)

Comment: @Chris the Im trying to make my program post those error messages for when I user enters those type of expressions

Comment: can you post the stack trace? To see those errors you have to expect them, either using try catch or validating everything before passing the arguments.

Comment: @Chris FYI learned recently the homework tag is deprecated http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Your calculate method is obviously wrong, you are basically doing a.length * `a.substring(0, '+')` (or even worse, `a.substring('+', '+' + 1). Remember that in java, a `char` has a numeric value..

Comment: @porfiriopartida I dont know what the stack trace is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
    char sign='+';
    a.indexOf(sign);   
    sum+=Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0,sign))+Integer.parseInt(a.substring(sign+1,sign));
```

`sign` is a character, and characters are actually integer values.  The character `'+'` has the value 43 (that's where the plus sign is on the ASCII chart).  So you're trying to compute `a.substring(0,43)`, which will get you an out-of-bounds error if `a` is shorter than 43 characters.

You used `indexOf` to find out where the `'+'` sign is, but you threw away the result.  Store the result of `indexOf` in a variable, then use that variable, not `sign`, in the `substring` calls.  Also make sure you handle the case when `indexOf` returns -1 (it can't find a plus sign); if you just pass that to `a.substring`, you'll get another out of bounds error.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Reverse Polish Notation which allows you to evaluate expressions. There is a video here that explains how it works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzVVjboyb0s